# Database first - EF6 On Mono

Tags: .net, entity-framework, msbuild, mono

**Context:**

I need to get a "legacy" .Net application working on my local machine which is a Macbook... (most of our stack is dotnetcore), but this specific application is a little older.

While I do realize it would be MUCH easier to probably just spin up a windows VM and build it in there, I'm taking a stab at getting the project building (and running using MONO)

So far I've resolved a few issues by adding some conditional checks in the `.csproj`, which got the application building and running... barely, as it dies when I hit the first API that checks the db for connectivity.

**Current Setup:**

- Mono JIT compiler version 5.18.1.3
- .Net Target 4.6.1
- Rider IDE (I have VS for OSX Installed as well)
- EF6.1.3

The project is structured as such:

```
Project.Data
  - App.Config
  - DataModel.edmx
Project.Api (which references the Project.Data) 
  - Web.Config
```

Both contain the following connection string (indented for brevity):

```
<add name="SomeEntities" 

connectionString="
metadata=
  res://*/DataModel.csdl|
  res://*/DataModel.ssdl|
  res://*/DataModel.msl;

provider=System.Data.SqlClient;

provider connection string=
  &quot;
    data source=somedb;
    initial catalog=some_catalog;
    user id=some_id;
    password=some_password;
    App=EntityFramework;
  &quot;
" 

providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**Problem:**

I think whats happening is that the regular build task DOES NOT generate the correct files from the `.edmx`, but as to how to do that on my current env... I'm starting to think its impossible.

Error:

```
Unable to load the specified metadata resource.
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources
```

I've seen various posts about modifying the connection string, all with various results, but never resulting in a functioning application.

Changing to, `metadata=res://*/;` results in:

```
Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied. 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityUtil.CheckArgumentEmpty[T]
```

Changing to a standard SqlConnection string:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException: 
The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715
```

**Question:**

Is this at all possible, or should I just revert getting a windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after traversing the web for a while, and asking on a few of the forums and groups, I've come to the conclusion that this might be a futile effort, especially considering that things like dotnetcore are commonplace these days.

Some more context on the [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/506294/view.html) answered by one of the devs on the VS Code for Mac team...

> On Windows there are some Microsoft.Data.Entity MSBuild tasks. These
>   are used to generate the various .csdl, .ssdl, and .msl files at build
>   time from the .edmx file. If you look at the build output in Visual
>   Studio on Windows you should see something similar to:
>
> Building target "EntityDeployEmbeddedResources" completely. Output
>   file "obj\Debug\edmsREsourcesToEmbed\Model.ssdl" does not exist. Using
>   "EntityDeploy" task from assembly
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll".
>   The Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll and the associated
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets file do not exist for the Mac.
>
> On the Mac the only workaround is to use Entity Framework Core which
>   is cross platform and not to use edmx files since these are not
>   supported.

Thus the options are:

- Port to dotnetcore, or
- Get a windows machine

...for this legacy app. And since we're migrating to dotnetcore either way... I believe the realistic solution is to prioritise porting of this specific item to dotnetcore.

Comment: giving up is not an answer.

Comment: But changing your approach is :) which if you read my answer... You'll see I've listed them. You might not like it... But it is a valid answer. I'd also love to sit and hack away at things forever, but sometimes business needs to go on ;)

Comment: ok, you're right. it's been a couple days and it's just not working. I even tried building in windows with an actual connection to the db, then deploying with to xsp then apache2/mod_mono. no dice. The same error persists. You can have your updoot back.

Comment: For the record, the migration to .net core was not super painful, though not as well documented in the darker corners as I'd hoped.

Comment: Wish I could say the same for our project which is a bit erm... older... we kind of have to piecemeal it at this stage. But it's good to know that there is light at the end of the tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

As now newer versions of EF, which have better cross platform support, are available, upgrading EF fixes the issue. (Upgraded from 6.2.0 to 6.4.4)

Comment: I tried this, but running on ubuntu with msbuild and 6.4 Entity Framework doesn't fix anything, the files are still not generated.

Comment: Weird, on OSX I upgraded from 6.2.0 to 6.4.4 and added this to the project settings
  <Import Project="..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props')" />
which solved the issue

Comment: Ah ok, I'll try that. Which file did you add this?

Comment: I added it to the csproj, but running the project after msbuild compiled it, still gave me the `unable to load the specified metadata resource` error. (Ubuntu)

Comment: in csproj. 
I think it's some other problem with your setup then. They did add support from cross platform from 6.3 and it works on my project which might have different settings and build steps than yours.

Comment: Ok, I'll dive into it a bit more to see if a fresh project or so works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I started a fresh project and imported only the source files and got it working! So it's actually possible with the newer 6.4 entity framework to build a project on Linux and deploy it with mono. Very nice and thanks for the help!